# Log for file access and ACL changes in Datalake storage Gen2

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Is there any way to view Acl change in  logs for Azure DatalakeGen2? The diagnostic settings for the resource is already on. But I am not able to see any entries for changes which are done by me or anyone else.
Example-> I remove/add some acls on particular path in AzureGen2 storage accounts. Is there any way where I can keep track of such activities which are triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the ACL related logs in **Activity Logs** in Azure Data Lake Storage account.

[image]

Refer official document for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-security-overview#activity-and-diagnostic-logs

Comment: I had tried that but i am just able to see logs only for administrators. I am making acl changes through app which has owner role but its not deflecting. What could be possible reasons for that?

Comment: It takes 2-3 minutes to reflect after ACL changes. Refresh it and check, it should show. Let me know if still not reflecting.

Comment: Hi @Ash3060, if you find this answer useful and it resolved your issue, please accept this as an answer (click on tick symbol on left side of the answer) to help the other community members.

Comment: Hi UtkarshPal-MT i am still not able to see it. I am trying to figure if i am missing anything from my side. I have read access and i am not admin.

Comment: Check if your Diagnostic settings (classic) is enabled and then try to create the role in IAM.

Comment: In IAM i can see that i have reader role for Diagnostic settings. Is this not enough to view it? Though i can see that i am not able to see those containers where logs are getting stored. But stii will this affect seeing logs under activity?

Comment: You need owner or at least contributor role to enable and check the diagnostic settings. Please make sure to enable diagnostic settings and then try to add the role. It should reflect in the Activity log.

Comment: The diagnostic settings are enabled by the admin and I have reader role. Ok will try to do and update in sometime

Comment: Btw there are two diagnostic settings. Classic one at storage resource level and one we can see after going inside activity log. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: The one which is outside activity log. On left side under monitoring you will find Diagnostic setting (classic). You need to enable and create new diagnostic setting if not created already. Also, if you have only reader permission in storage account, I doubt that activity logs would be available for you.

Comment: Aha cool thanks for helping. So the general thing is like enable classic logs first and then go under Activity logs and set diagnostic settings under that tab? I thought that only through diagnostic logs we can get all the logs.

Comment: Yes, it's diagnostic service and activity logs combo. So now is it reflecting in the activity log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238607/discussion-between-ash3060-and-utkarshpal-mt).